# How can I get the radius or diameter of each cluster in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis

I have four defined clusters but I don't know how to get the radius or diameter of each one of them. Not sure if there's a function in OpenCV or Numpy to do it.

```
model = KMeans(init=centers, n_clusters=4, max_iter = 50)
model.fit(x)
```

Comment: Please specify which module your `KMeans` class is sourced from...

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful [Scipy Spatial distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` compute distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs. So the maximum distance in Cdist when applied to a single cluster itself, is diameter of a cluster (if you know that your clusters are circular or semi-circular)

Answer (score 0):

Since k-means does not use either, you will have to compute these yourself.

And in fact, you will first have to *define* them yourself.

An easy to compute definition would be that the radius is the maximum distance from the cluster center (as found by k-means), and that the diameter is twice the radius. This model is easy to compute and consistent with the cluster center of k-means.

Is this optimal? No. K-means does not attempt to minimize the radius. It minimizes squared distances, so it does not even minimize the average (nor the maximum) Euclidean distance. But it is easy to computer, and because you use k-means it makes most sense to do it this way.

Alternatively, you could define the diameter as the maximum distance of any two points in the cluster, and the radius as half of that. But then you would **not know where** the center of that circle would be, and whether you could really draw a circle like this around the data, or if the data points are in an odd shape.